# Pushing a variable number of objects into a function using C++?

Tags: c++, object, vector

I have a variable number of objects all from the same class, which I would like to pass to a function. The objects are just 8-dimensional "points" which are used to define motion positions, and I want to pass them to a function to separate parts of each object into other vectors (rotation, translation).

I don't know if it would be simpler to store each class object in a multi-dimensional array, and pass that to the function along with an integer of the number of points. I'm not quite sure how to do that either though, so any help is greatly appreciated!

```
// Define motion points as 'global' for testing purposes
// Eventually can be read from file
// Defined to match constructor
double v0 = 1;
Point8D M0(v0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);                        // First position, no rotation
Point8D M1(v0, 2, 1.5, 1, 1 / sqrt(2), 0, 1 / sqrt(2), 0);  // 90deg about y
Point8D M2(v0, 0, 1.5, 2, 1 / sqrt(2), 0, 1 / sqrt(2), 0);  // Translation, no rotation from 2nd pos
Point8D M3(v0, 2, 3, 1.5, 0, 1 / sqrt(2), 1 / sqrt(2), 0);  // 180 about y, 90 about x
Point8D M4(v0, 3, 2, 3, 1 / sqrt(2), 0, -1 / sqrt(2), 0);   // 270 about y
Point8D M5(v0, 5, 4, 3.5, 1 / sqrt(2), -1 / sqrt(2), 0, 0); // -90 about z
Point8D M6(v0, 8, 5, 5.5, 1, 0, 1 / sqrt(2), -1 / sqrt(2)); // 180 about y, 90 about z
int numPosn = 7;
```

Comment: Take a `std::vector` of points?

Comment: `1 / sqrt(2)` and `-1 / sqrt(2)` are constants.  No need to keep computing them, just use the constants.

Comment: @Walter the function is not explicitly defined yet, but the Point8D is defined as such because the input from the user will be entered as is shown here (or read from a file).  What I need to be able to do is apply a different mathematical function to the first point of the objects, then the second point of the objects, etc. 

What I had planned to do was parse the input using a function of some form, then use those values to define vectors for each of the eight parameters. I can't alter how the input is accepted, but everything else can be changed.

Comment: If the function can be defined recursively, you could use a variadic template function. If not, you could accept a single argument `std::initializer_list<Point8D>`, which could be called like `your_function({M0, M1, M2, M3...})`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The compiler will optimize that out most probably.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ah thank you, I should have caught that already.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you're later going to read the points from a file. I would suggest you read them, from the file, into a std vector of Point8D's. Then make your function expect a Point8D vector as its parameter.

Comment: So simply define (1D) vector<Point8D> motionPosn, and pass that into the function? This definitely makes more sense, now that I'm thinking about it, because the number of points is explicitly defined so iteration will be straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You may just use functions for single `Point8D` and then work with containers of the latter. For example

```
void split(Point8D const&x, Point3D&rot, Point3D&trans)
{
  /* ... */
}

std::vector<Point8D> P;
/* ... code to fill P */

std::vector<Point3D> R(P.size()), T(P.size());
for(size_t i=0; i!=P.size(); ++i)
  split(T[i], R[i], T[i]);
```